# RGB Matrix flickering every ~5 seconds when paired with SoftwareSerial

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, rgb-led

I'm running an RGB matrix through an Uno and trying to run it alongside SoftwareSerial so that I can integrate an ESP8266 into things. The trouble is, when I start introducing the SoftwareSerial into things, the screen flickers every few seconds, consistently. For example, with this function, it flickers exactly every 10 seconds. Any ideas what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Below is the arduino code. The RGB matrix is configured like [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix/connecting-with-jumper-wires).

```
#include <RGBmatrixPanel.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define CLK  8   // USE THIS ON ARDUINO UNO, ADAFRUIT METRO M0, etc.
//#define CLK A4 // USE THIS ON METRO M4 (not M0)
//#define CLK 11 // USE THIS ON ARDUINO MEGA
#define OE   9
#define LAT 10
#define A   A0
#define B   A1
#define C   A2
#define setDelay 500

RGBmatrixPanel matrix(A, B, C, CLK, LAT, OE, false);

SoftwareSerial mySerial(11, 12); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.println("Start Serial!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");

  matrix.begin();
}

void loop() {

  // draw a pixel in white
  matrix.drawPixel(0, 0, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 7));
  delay(setDelay);

  // fix the screen with green
  matrix.fillRect(0, 0, 32, 16, matrix.Color333(0, 7, 0));
  delay(setDelay);

  // draw a box in yellow
  matrix.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 16, matrix.Color333(7, 7, 0));
  delay(setDelay);

  // draw an 'X' in red
  matrix.drawLine(0, 0, 31, 15, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
  matrix.drawLine(31, 0, 0, 15, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
  delay(setDelay);

  // draw a blue circle
  matrix.drawCircle(7, 7, 7, matrix.Color333(0, 0, 7));
  delay(setDelay);

  // fill a violet circle
  matrix.fillCircle(23, 7, 7, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 7));
  delay(setDelay);

  // fill the screen with black
  matrix.fillScreen(matrix.Color333(0, 0, 0));

  // draw some text!
  matrix.setCursor(1, 0);  // start at top left, with one pixel of spacing
  matrix.setTextSize(1);   // size 1 == 8 pixels high

  // print each letter with a rainbow color
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,0,0));
  matrix.print('1');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,4,0));
  matrix.print('6');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,7,0));
  matrix.print('x');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(4,7,0));
  matrix.print('3');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0,7,0));
  matrix.print('2');

  matrix.setCursor(1, 9);  // next line
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0,7,7));
  matrix.print('*');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0,4,7));
  matrix.print('R');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(0,0,7));
  matrix.print('G');
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(4,0,7));
  matrix.print("B");
  matrix.setTextColor(matrix.Color333(7,0,4));
  matrix.print("*");
  }
```

Comment: Does it coincide with when data arrives on the software serial pins?

Comment: Oh come to think of it, it sure does!

Comment: Welcome to the world of SoftwareSerial. Nothing (and I mean *nothing*) else can happen when data is being either sent *or* received.

Comment: This should be a fairly easy fix, though. I wonder if there's a way to sync the ESP8266 clock with the Uno receiving so I can basically say "do this every 10 seconds, but not when the ESP8266 is sending!"

Comment: It all depends on what the ESP8266 is doing. If you have your own firmware on there you could make it call-and-response so it never sends anything unless asked to by the Arduino.

Comment: That makes sense. But in that short period where the Uno asked for something from the ESP8266 and the ESP8266 returned it, the Uno still wouldn't be able to display anything to the matrix without flickering, right? Would this be a problem if I were using the hardware serial? I would go that route but it seems like it makes debugging a lot harder!

Comment: Hardware serial will do way better. Then only the processing of the received data needs time, not the receiving itself. Also you can ditch the delays and use `millis()` like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, so that you can do other things (for example serial), while waiting for the time to pass.